# Find the longest integer from when concatenated inside a grid

Tags: python, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

For a given matrix, The longest integer of length 4 is 9121

```
A = [
[9, 1, 1, 0, 7],
[1, 0, 2, 1, 0],
[1, 9, 1, 1, 0],
]
rows = 3
cols = 5
```

This is my Python code
For the given row and col `(i, j)`
I am trying to find out all the paths of length four

```
def find_the_path(A, rows, cols, i, j):
    stack = []
    count = 0
    result = []
    seen = set()
    stack.append((i, j))
    while stack:
        if length(result) == 4:
            result = result[1:]
            seen.clear()

        x, y = stack.pop()
        result.append(A[x][y])
        seen.add(A[x][y])
        count += 1
        # Checking right, left, down, up
        # Trying to use stack, so that I can pop the last element
        # Storing the result in a list and checking for length 4
        for d in ((0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)):
            next_x, next_y = x + d[0], y + d[1]
            if 0 <= next_x < rows and 0 <= next_y < cols:
                if A[next_x][next_y] not in seen and length(result) < 4:
                    stack.append((next_x, next_y))
                    # result.append(A[next_x][next_y])
                    seen.add(A[next_x][next_y])
                    count += 1
                if length(result) == 4:
                    print(result)
                    break
```

I am not sure why this is not printing elements from `[0,1]`

The above code prints

```
9,1,1,9
1,1,9,0
1,9,0,1
```

I have spent lot of my time without Googling it and not able to finish this.
I don't need code, I need an approach to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

one line of the zen of python (type `import this` in a python terminal) is

> Simple is better than complex.

Your attempting to make a depth first search.
depth first search is a recursive algorithm.
generally you can implement a recursive algorithm in two ways: procedural and recursive.

the procedural way is in my view more complicated but often has better performance and is less limited by memory then the recursive way.

the recursive way in python is in my experience simpler to read and write. but it is more limited by memory the procedural way.

because your looking at a small depth of 4 steps, i think it is easier to use a recursive approach.

---

Your implementation sometimes uses points (`(x, y)`) and sometimes values (`1`).
your implementation will be simpler if you use points to build the path, and then make a new path that stores values instead of points when your ready to return.

---

your constructing neigbour points (next_x, next_y) in your algorithm.
i would put that part in a seperate function.

```
def neigbours(x, y, rows, cols):
    for rel_x, rel_y in [(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)]:
        next_x, next_y = x + rel_x, y + rel_y
        if 0 <= next_x < rows and 0 <= next_y < cols:
            yield next_x, next_y

# so that you can do the following
rows, cols = 3, 5
x, y = 0, 0
for next_x, next_y in neigbours(x, y, rows, cols):
    print(next_x, next_y)

# output
0 1
1 0
```